# Heroku code=H14 No web processes running - Docker image

Tags: docker, heroku

I have a Django project that I'm trying to deploy to Heroku. According to my activity log, deployment is successful. However I can't open the app, and when looking at the logs, it says `at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running"`

This error is all over the place on google searches and everyone is suggesting to run `heroku ps:scale web=1`. When I run this command I get `Scaling dynos... done, now running web at 1:Free`. However, when I run `heroku ps` I get `No dynos on ....`.

I'm using Docker, so the deployment is a bit different from the conventional way.

heroku.yml file:

```
setup:
    addons:
        - plan: heroku-postgresql
build:
    docker:
        web: Dockerfile
release:
    image: web
    command:
      - python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
run:
    web: gunicorn app_name.wsgi
```

docker-compose file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    web:
        build: .
        command: gunicorn app_name.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000
        volumes:
            - .:/app_name
        ports:
            - 8000:8000
        depends_on:
            - db
        environment:
            - ENVIRONMENT=production
            - SECRET_KEY= ...
            - DEBUG=0
    db:
        image: postgres:11
        volumes:
            - postgres_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
volumes:
    postgres_data:
```

It's also worth mentioning that I've run the following command

```
heroku stack:set container -a app_name
```

Also, on my heroku dashboard, I have the following:
[image]

My environment variables are also set-up on Heroku. These are `database_url`, `Debug`, `Environment`, `secret_key` (all in upper-case).

Comment: Have you solved it? I'm having a similar type of problem

Comment: Not yet @TasnimReza

Comment: Didi you solved it now @HadiFarhat

Comment: I haven't abu 3lesh @alial-karaawi

Answer (score 0):

you need to set

```
heroku stack:set container
```

otherwise heroku will choose the default stack type and will ignore Dockerfile.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).